# Combine Multiple Forms

Tags: php, forms, submit

Is there anyway to combine two forms into one action? As in, having form 1 values when form 2 is submitted. I tried using the same `name`, but with no luck.

```
<form action='result.php' method='post' name='form' id='form_1'>
    <input name='value_1' placeholder='value_1' />
    <input name='value_2' placeholder='value_1' />
</form>

<form action='result.php' method='post' name='form' id='form_2'>
    <select name='value_3'>
        <option value='a'>a</option>
        <option value='b'>b</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to get value_1, value_2, and value_3 when the submit button is pressed. The thing is, I can't use the `form` attribute on the second form, because my second form is a template used on multiple pages, stored in a separate variable. Is there anyway around without?

Comment: How about making them into 1 form then...?

Comment: The only way I see is to join both forms into single using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. I used `form='parent'` for form_2, and put `id='parent'` in form_1. Downside is now I have to name every form `id='parent'`...

Haven't tried, I'm thinking if I used `form='parent'` for both forms, then make a hidden `<form id='parent>'`, I might be able to combine even more forms. Not perfect... but at least it's working, with plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you re-structure your templates so they can be used in conjunction with one another.

However, if the templates are fixed, then you can use javascript to intercept the submit on either form, grab the data from both forms, and submit a new form.

Answer (score 0):

you can do so

```
<form action='result.php?action=form1' method='post' name='form' id='form_1'>
    <input name='value_1' placeholder='value_1' />
    <input name='value_2' placeholder='value_1' />
</form>

<form action='result.php?action=form2' method='post' name='form' id='form_2'>
    <select name='value_3'>
        <option value='a'>a</option>
        <option value='b'>b</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

on your PHP file :

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];

if($action === 'form1'){
    #do something
}else{
    #do something
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit? I can't seem to get it working.